# Sum of certain elements in an array in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have an array like this :

```
1717.531
1717.364
1716.725
1716.723
1716.536
1716.304
1716.221
1715.998
1715.799
1715.702
1715.648
1715.254
1715.186
1714.733
1714.532
1714.266
1714.223
1714.094
1713.943
1713.873
1713.803
1713.578
```

I want to SUM each 5 elements separately, which function to use and how?

Comment: `SUM` is almost certainly what you want, but are you after summing: elements 1 to 5, and 6 to 10, etc.; elements 1 to 5, and 2 to 6, 3 to 7, etc.; elements 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, and 2, 7, 12, ... etc?

Comment: From 1 to 5 then from 6 to 10 then from 11 to 15 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a loop with a step size:

```
do i=1, N, 5
```

Then the intrinsic function sum applied to slices of the array:

```
sum (a(i: i+4))
```

Comment: Or if one doesn't mind an array copy, `sum` with `dim=` and a `reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be this:

```
do i=1,20,5                     
    x=0.0                 
    x=(sum(a(i:i+4)))
    write(*,*) x           
end do
```